# How to permute values in a single row of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some messy data that requires me to split it up as a combination of values. This is sort of what it looks like:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"Name":["name1", "name2"], 
        "A": [[1, 2, 3], [1]], 
        "B": [["a", "b"], ["a"]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

And I would like to permute the two columns with list data so that the resulting dataframe carries each combination of pairs in individual rows like so:

```
{"Name": ["name1", "name1", "name1", "name1", "name1", "name1", "name2"],
 "A": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1], 
 "B": ["a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a"]}
```

How do I do this while keeping non combined columns along side them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the two columns successively:

```
df.explode('A').explode('B', ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
    Name  A  B
0  name1  1  a
1  name1  1  b
2  name1  2  a
3  name1  2  b
4  name1  3  a
5  name1  3  b
6  name2  1  a
```

If you have more than two columns, you could use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['name1', 'name2'],
                   'A': [[1, 2, 3], [1]],
                   'B': [['a', 'b'], ['a']],
                   'C': [['w', 'x'], ['y', 'z']]
                  })

out = reduce(lambda a, b: a.explode(b, ignore_index=True),
             ['A', 'B', 'C'], df)
```

Or a python loop:

```
out = df
for col in ['A', 'B', 'C']:
    out = out.explode(col, ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
     Name  A  B  C
0   name1  1  a  w
1   name1  1  a  x
2   name1  1  b  w
3   name1  1  b  x
4   name1  2  a  w
5   name1  2  a  x
6   name1  2  b  w
7   name1  2  b  x
8   name1  3  a  w
9   name1  3  a  x
10  name1  3  b  w
11  name1  3  b  x
12  name2  1  a  y
13  name2  1  a  z
```

Comment: @Anonymous you're welcome, I added a generalization to an arbitrary number of columns if needed

Answer (score 1):

This is the output of original df:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"Name":["name1", "name2"], 
        "A": [[1, 2, 3], [1]], 
        "B": [["a", "b"], ["a"]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

[image]

This is a simple logic to achieve the permutation you want:

```
A = []
B = []
Name = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    TA = []
    TB = []
    for e in df.iloc[i]['A']:
        for f in df.iloc[i]['B']:
            TA.append(e)
            TB.append(f)
    Name += [df.iloc[i]['Name']] * len(TA)
    A += TA
    B += TB
data = {'Name':Name, 'A':A, 'B':B}
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]